# Am I invisible on WI-Fi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-11

When I log on my Wi-Fi in Windows 11, it recommends me to select "Public" and not "Private". Because I will be invisible on "Public".

But then I'm wondering if I really am invisible to other Wi-Fi networks on the list.  Shouldn't I then be able to see them on the list?

I want my Wi-Fi to be invisible - especially to hackers.

Comment: If a hacker is sitting within wifi range of your home or other such place... you probably have deeper problems

Answer (score 1):

> When I log on my Wi-Fi in Windows 11, it recommends me to select "Public" and not "Private". Because I will be invisible on "Public".

No, you will not be entirely invisible. You will be *inaccessible.*

The choices mostly just select one of two Windows Firewall profiles. While choosing "Public" does turn off SMB file-sharing advertisements, it does not turn off discovery in other apps (e.g. Steam, Dropbox), merely prevents them from receiving unwanted connections; and of course it cannot turn off things like ARP that are necessary for your network access to work at all.

> But then I'm wondering if I really am invisible to other Wi-Fi networks on the list. Shouldn't I then be able to see them on the list?

You being able to see others has nothing to do with others seeing you. You can still passively receive packets (e.g. network advertisements) while being invisible, and vice versa, others can see your packets while staying invisible to you.

Only the Windows "Network Discovery" feature happens to conflate the two, but it's only a single feature out of many that relate to "visibility".

(And more specifically, the option you select has no effect on the network; it only makes the computer block incoming access *for* this network, but doesn't change how the network itself works.)

> I want my Wi-Fi to be invisible - especially to hackers.

That's impossible to achieve with Wi-Fi. Both the client device and the "network" (access point) will reveal themselves to each other, by necessity, as soon as they attempt to connect (or really even before that – networks announce their existence, and if you try to make a network "hidden" then the client device will actively search for it instead).

Focus on making your computer/network inaccessible, not invisible.

Answer (score 0):

When logging on WIFI in Windows 11, you're doing it inside the local area
network (LAN) that is created by the router. Computers inside the LAN
are not visible on the internet, so are not reachable by hackers.

Inside the LAN (unless you fear one of the household members)
there is no great meaning to the difference between Private and Public.

If you wish to interact with other devices on the LAN inside your house,
then choose to designate the network as Private. If you live inside a
dormitory or are connecting inside a public internet cafe or similar,
and you don't intend to interact with others, then choose Public.

Inside your home, Private is usually the right choice.

---

If you wish your computer to be inaccessible on the network,
you need rather to **disable network discovery**, so your computer
will refuse any type of access from other computers or devices
(except of course from the router).

From the article
[Turn sharing on or off](http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-6ddfa83c-01c8-441e-b041-1fd912c3fe60/):

> Network discovery is a setting that affects whether your computer can see (find) other computers and devices on the network and whether other computers on the network can see your computer.

Here is how to do that in Windows 11 :

- Open the Settings app.
- Choose *Network & internet* from the left-side menu
- Click *Advanced network settings*
- Click *Advanced sharing settings*
- Under Private or Public networks (as is your choice),
  set the *File and printer sharing* toggle to off.

Comment: But Then I´m wondering why they are visible to me, when I log on WIFI in my apartment..?  They might do it from a mobile,  since they are visible to me...?  :)

Comment: You might be referring to [network discovery](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-turn-on-network-discovery-windows-11/).